# Is there any way to create a HTML element from a DOM "element"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

To get an element from an html page, one uses a DOM method such as `.getElementById()`. This method returns a Javascript object that contains an extensive list of the element's properties. The following is example is from a page in the MDN docs, focused on a header with `id="Syntax"`.
[Here is the link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes#Syntax)

*This list is not in format because I copied it from the browser console.

> >
>   17:38:20.198 h2#SyntaxaccessKey: ""accessKeyLabel: ""align: ""attributes: NamedNodeMap [ id="Syntax", name="Syntax" ]baseURI: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes"childElementCount: 1childNodes: NodeList [ #text, a.button.section-edit.only-icon ]children: HTMLCollection [ a.button.section-edit.only-icon ]classList: DOMTokenList []className: ""clientHeight: 48clientLeft: 0clientTop: 0clientWidth: 1019contentEditable: "inherit"contextMenu: nulldataset: DOMStringMap {  }dir: ""draggable: falsefirstChild: #text "Syntax"firstElementChild: hidden: falseid: "Syntax"innerHTML: "SyntaxEdit"innerText: "Syntax\nEdit"isConnected: trueisContentEditable: falselang: ""lastChild: lastElementChild: localName: "h2"namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"nextElementSibling: nextSibling: #text "
>   "nodeName: "H2"nodeType: 1nodeValue: nulloffsetHeight: 48offsetLeft: 0offsetParent: offsetTop: 231offsetWidth: 1019onabort: nullonanimationcancel: nullonanimationend: nullonanimationiteration: nullonanimationstart: nullonauxclick: nullonblur: nulloncanplay: nulloncanplaythrough: nullonchange: nullonclick: nullonclose: nulloncontextmenu: nulloncopy: nulloncut: nullondblclick: nullondrag: nullondragend: nullondragenter: nullondragexit: nullondragleave: nullondragover: nullondragstart: nullondrop: nullondurationchange: nullonemptied: nullonended: nullonerror: nullonfocus: nulloninput: nulloninvalid: nullonkeydown: nullonkeypress: nullonkeyup: nullonload: nullonloadeddata: nullonloadedmetadata: nullonloadend: nullonloadstart: nullonmousedown: nullonmouseenter: nullonmouseleave: nullonmousemove: nullonmouseout: nullonmouseover: nullonmouseup: nullonmozfullscreenchange: nullonmozfullscreenerror: nullonpaste: nullonpause: nullonplay: nullonplaying: nullonprogress: nullonratechange: nullonreset: nullonresize: nullonscroll: nullonseeked: nullonseeking: nullonselect: nullonselectstart: nullonshow: nullonstalled: nullonsubmit: nullonsuspend: nullontimeupdate: nullontoggle: nullontransitioncancel: nullontransitionend: nullontransitionrun: nullontransitionstart: nullonvolumechange: nullonwaiting: nullonwebkitanimationend: nullonwebkitanimationiteration: nullonwebkitanimationstart: nullonwebkittransitionend: nullonwheel: nullouterHTML: "SyntaxEdit"ownerDocument: HTMLDocument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributesparentElement: parentNode: prefix: nullpreviousElementSibling:
>
> previousSibling: #text "
>   "scrollHeight: 49scrollLeft: 0scrollLeftMax: 0scrollTop: 0scrollTopMax: 0scrollWidth: 1019spellcheck: falsestyle: CSS2Properties {  }tabIndex: -1tagName: "H2"textContent: "SyntaxEdit"title: ""**proto**: HTMLHeadingElementPrototype { align: Getter & Setter, … }

Using this list, is it possible to create an html element?

Comment: It might help to describe what you're aiming to accomplish, big picture.

Comment: @showdev, creating an HTML element from a javascript object _is_ what I am trying to accomplish. It is an important part of another project I am making.

Comment: `document.createElement("div")` would create a div element. what is your question?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell, I don't see how that helps.

Comment: What I mean is, why? This sounds like the long way around, but I'm not sure of your ultimate goal.

Comment: @showdev, does it really matter why?

Comment: Hm. I guess not!

Comment: @showdev, my comment came off rude. I just meant that this is the only way to do what I am trying to do, and even if it isn't I still want to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand what you're seeing. Any of the querySelector type js methods *do* return a direct reference to the DOM element(s) in memory, not a mere list of attributes. All the console.log() output you're seeing is for your convenience. So, it already is an html element.

If you want to create a new element of a type, use `document.createElement('type')`. If you wish to create a copy of an existing element/node, use `cloneNode` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode.

Comment: As a clarifying (hopefully) example:
Sending and receiving parts of an HTML document as JSON and then writing the document into the current page.

Comment: Sort of like getting all the information about an element and sending it. The receiver can then write or store the element in an object format, and the write it out in HTML when requested.